# How to Re-use extensions across multiple View Controllers - Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, extension-methods

I have these two extensions in one of my view controllers

```
extension InformationViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.endEditing(true)
    return true
}

@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textfield: UITextField) {
   print("text field did change") 
}
}

extension InformationViewController {
func setupToHideKeyboardOnTapOnView()
{
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
        target: self,
        action: #selector(InformationViewController.dismissKeyboard))

    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

@objc func dismissKeyboard()
{
    view.endEditing(true)
}
}
```

I need to use these two extensions across multiple view controllers. What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Explain your question in detail what you need exactly.

Comment: Inheritance and/or protocols